# Invalid value for key attachdbfilename

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, aspnetdb

I try to run my asp net application in godaddy webserver and get error:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key ‘attachdbfilename’.
```

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name=”LocalSqlServer”/>
<add name=”LocalSqlServer” connectionString=”Data Source=(LocalDB)v11.0;Integrated     Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf”        providerName=”System.Data.SqlClient”/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any ideas how could I fix this? I dont have this error on my pc.

Comment: You do have the Database.mdf file in the App_Data folder on the server, correct?  Also, are you sure GoDaddy allows attaching the database?

Comment: Yes I have it in App_Data folder. Well I dont know if godaddy allows that. What could I do if it doesnt?

Comment: I think it sowsnt allow attaching databases. I neet to create database manually in control panel.

Comment: I was thinking that may be it.  You can also use the generate scripts feature to generate both the schema and data as a quick copy over, if it doesn't let you upload your MDF.

Comment: Better late than never, in your connection string, your Data source is missing a slash See: `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0`

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, I had the same problem, in my case i did not have LocalDB installed, so how about you check for that!!